# Save changes with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am new to python and an using openpyxl to edit an xlsx file. I am having an issue trying to save the original file. It seems that openpyxl keeps making me save the changes as a new xlsx.

Here is the code I am using and get the error TypeError: save() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('book1.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sensor Status")
sheet['I3'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",C:C,"=0")'
sheet['I4'] = '=countifs(B:B,"*server*",C:C,">=0")'
wb.save()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sir,

You need to add the file name like:

```
wb.save('book1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Well that was simple enough, I could have sworn I tried that and it gave me an error about there already being a file with that name. Guess I was wrong, thank you much.

Comment: @LordBeerus No worry. I make silly mistakes everyday. Could you accept the answer if my answer helps you? There is one [check] button below [Vote up/down]. Or you can delete your post if you want.

Answer (score 5):

Gen Wan's answer is already correct. But, assuming you already did that and you still had an error, this might help you. I had the same problem, and I figured out that it gave me an error because my file was still open in Microsoft Excel while I was trying to save it with openpyxl. When the one same file is opened by two platforms (Which in this case are Microsoft Excel and openpyxl), I think that the priviledge to save the file is prioritized for the Microsoft Excel software, that's why it's declining the save command from openpyxl. Once I closed Microsoft Excel, I no longer had the error and I was able to save the file. I am assuming you had the error because of that too.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32567909)